# Excel Execute stored proc with dates

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to execute a stored proc from vba however the data is not being returned. The formats of the dates have to be yyyy-mm-dd. Which I set using the custom format option on the cell but still no data.

How do i tell excel what row to start the data at when it is sucesfull

```
Private Sub Refresh_Click()
  On Error GoTo eh:
Dim DateFrom As Date  'Declare the SellStartDate as Date
Dim DateTo As Date    'Declare the SellEndDate as Date

SellStartDate = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("B2").Value
SellEndDate = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("B3").Value

'Pass the Parameters values to the Stored Procedure used in the Data Connection
With ActiveWorkbook.Connections("NewConnection").OLEDBConnection.CommandText = "EXECUTE [dbo].[mystoredprocIwantorun] @DateFrom = '" & DateFrom & "', @DateTo = '" & DateTo & "'"
ActiveWorkbook.Connections("NewConnection").Refresh


Done:
    Exit Sub
eh:
    MsgBox "The following error occurred: " & Err.Description
End With

End Sub
```

When I click the button no error is generated and when I run this query below in sql management studio data does return I masked the stored proc names for security. Strange thing is no error is generated.

The following is what I run in SSMS and it works and returns data.

```
DECLARE @return_value int

EXEC    @return_value = [dbo].[mystoredprocIwantorun]
        @DateFrom = '2018/01/01',
        @DateTo = '2018/01/31'

SELECT  'Return Value' = @return_value

GO
```

When I look at the sql string it's showing only this.

> Watch :   : Sql : "EXECUTE [dbo].[mystoredproc] @DateFrom =
>   '00:00:00', @DateTo = '00:00:00'" : String : Sheet1.Refresh_Click

**Edit 1**
I noticed a couple of errors and corrected my code but still no data into excel

```
Private Sub Refresh_Click()
  On Error GoTo eh:
Dim DateFrom As Date  'Declare the SellStartDate as Date
Dim DateTo As Date    'Declare the SellEndDate as Date

SellStartDate = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("B2").Value
SellEndDate = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("B3").Value

Dim sql As String
sql = "EXECUTE [dbo].[myproctorun] @DateFrom = '" & SellStartDate & "', @DateTo = '" & SellEndDate & "'"

'Pass the Parameters values to the Stored Procedure used in the Data Connection
With ActiveWorkbook.Connections("NewConnection").OLEDBConnection.CommandText = "EXECUTE [dbo].[fsp_PLReportByDates] @DateFrom = '" & SellStartDate & "', @DateTo = '" & SellEndDate  & "'"
ActiveWorkbook.Connections("NewConnection").Refresh


Done:
    Exit Sub
eh:
    MsgBox "The following error occurred: " & Err.Description
End With

End Sub
```

I am still having issues with the connection not returning the data to the work sheet.

[image]

How do I return the data from the query to the work sheet can anyone help me out ?

Comment: Why was this down voted !

Comment: Not sure why this was down-voted. The question seems fairly well-written. It isn't quite a [mcve] (which is possibly the reason for the down-vote) but the "A" in  "VBA" implies that questions about using it sometimes depart from that ideal.

Comment: Thank you john i think the query is executing ok now but its not putting the data onto the sheet

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One issue is that your date format within your VBA generated string will NOT be formatted according to the cell format.  Suggest you use either the `.Text` property of those date cells, or, more bulletproof, format the stored value in your VBA macro.

```
SellStartDate = Format(Sheets("Sheet1").Range("B2").Value2, "yyyy-mm-dd")
SellEndDate = Format(Sheets("Sheet1").Range("B3").Value2, "yyyy-mm-dd")
```

Comment: Ron thanks that worked how do I tell the data to go to the sheet its not excueting that part.

Comment: This partially answered my question so will mark it as an answer.

Comment: @DavidB You'll have to debug your Connection Properties, but I don't have time to help you with that now.

Comment: @DavidB I suggest you create a new question about getting the data to the proper worksheet.  With this question marked as Answered, many knowledgeable folk may not even look at it.